# How can I change the text of a child element?

Tags: jquery, select, onchange, custom-data-attribute

I want to change the text of a child element, selected by data attribute:

```js
$('.service').change(function () {
     var dataid = $(this).data('id');
     var status = $(this).val();
     console.log(dataid);
     $(".productdetails[data-product_id='" + dataid + "']").find(".status_result").text(status);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="productdetails" data-product_id="91"><td class="status_result"><span class="label label-primary">in process </span></td>
</tr>


<select class="service" data-id="91">
      <option selected="">in process</option>
      <option>done</option>
</select>
```

But the text is not changing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, you can't have `<tr>` and `<td>` outside `<table>`. When you fix the HTML the code works.

```js
$('.service').change(function() {
  var dataid = $(this).data('id');
  var status = $(this).val();
  console.log(dataid);
  $(".productdetails[data-product_id='" + dataid + "']").find(".status_result").text(status);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="productdetails" data-product_id="91">
    <td class="status_result"><span class="label label-primary">in process </span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<select class="service" data-id="91">
      <option selected="">in process</option>
      <option>done</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
$('.service').change(function() {
  var dataid = $(this).data('id');
  var status = $(this).val();
  $(".productdetails[data-product_id='" + dataid + "']").find(".status_result").text(status);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="productdetails" data-product_id="91">
    <td class="status_result"><span class="label label-primary">in process </span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<select class="service" data-id="91">
      <option selected="">in process</option>
      <option>done</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why should he "try this"? Explain the problem, and what you did to fix it.